# Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, appcelerator, apple-watch, appcelerator-titanium

I have updated a currently submitted Titanium app and added a watch extension using swift.

Everything works fine if I build and test on sim and build directly to device. I only get an issue when I submit the app to the Apple app store (via XCode Organizer).

The binary submits, passing validation but I get am email from iTunes Connect as follows:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "xxxxxxxxxxx". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

It seems as though it may be related to a build setting: *Embedded Content Contains Swift Code*.

It looks like this needs to be set to **Yes** if the Titanium project contains embedded Swift.

As of now I am stuck as I cannot submit the app. Is this a Ti problem or is there another step I should follow?

XCode: 7.3, SDK: 5.2.2.GA - Project created and built using only the Ti CLI.

Comment: Are you using the Xcode 7.3 GA version from the AppStore (no beta)? Also make sure your appc-cli ist up2date by running `appc setup`. If it still persists, compare your watchos-template with the latest recommended [here](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19455).

Comment: Yes as specified above, 7.3 release version from the App Store. Watch template generated with the CLI option using the watch-os2 swift option so template auto generated by CLI

Comment: Has anyone used Swift for a watch app in a Ti project and actually managed to successfully upload the binary to the app store and had it accepted?

Comment: Appcelerator support suggested setting the  **Embedded Content Contains Swift Code** setting to **Yes** in the Ti SDK folder, which I did and tried a re-build. But I still have the same issue,

Comment: Thanks Steve, I've reported this under https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23313. Could you try setting the *Embedded Content Contains Swift Code* to *Yes* in the extension Xcode project for both targets? So not the Titanium generated project, but that of the extension. Let's discuss further on JIRA.

Comment: @user805981 There is supposed to be a fix in 6.0.1.GA of the SDK release, but I have not had time to try this yet. See  https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23313 for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now be resolved, there is a new version of the Titanium SDK, 6.0.1.GA  that specifically has a fix in for this issue. I have now created, submitted and have a Titanium app with associated watch app now published in the app store.

Answer (score 4):

First you should check your .ipa file by

```
unzip yourapp.ipa
```

If the only `Payload` exists, the Apple reject your app.

You should create `SwiftSupport/iphoneos` directory and put the appropriate
swift library files.

You can know which libraries are necessary by checking `Payload/yourapp.app/Framesworks`. But this library files can not be used as `SwiftSupport/iphoneos`.

You must copy the appropriate libraries from your mac's `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos` directory. The file names are same as the above `Payload/yourapp.app/Frameworks` but the contents are different.

After you get the `Payload` and `SwiftSupport` directory, do package these directories by

```
$ zip -r yournewapp.ipa Payload SwiftSupport
```

(Remark: remove all `.DS_Store` files if exist)

Then Apple accespt `yournewapp.ipa`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. If you don't like command line tool, use "commander one" tool for zipping and remove the hidden files.

Comment: how did you remove all dstore files

Comment: For example, find .DS_Store files by `find . -type f | grep .DS_Store`. Then remove each file.

Comment: In the latest xcode, `xcodebuild archive` command creates automatically SwiftSupport directory. Do you use `xcodebuild archive` command with suitable options?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: I had to Archive the Titanium project through Xcode because one of my third-party libraries requested to execute a script in the Build phases.

Received the same message from Apple and fortunately fixed it just changing the **Embedded Content Contains Swift Code** to **No**.

Comment: this should be fixed in TiSDK 6.0.0, here the ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23313

Comment: This issue has been fixed, tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose "Save for iOS App Store Deployment" option at the time of exporting ipa file.[image]